How do I submit requests to REST api in batches in SpringBoot?
I have a list of bulk request objects like
List<BulkRequests> bulkRequest;

I want submit them one by one to an external REST API
I have already built a FiegnClient for that.
Is there any optimised way to submit them one by one (submit next one only when the last one succeeds or in reactive manner) ?
The bulk request class is something like this.
class BulkRequest {
  String traceId;
  List<MyRequest> myRequests;
}


For that you should maybe follow a reactive approach for send bulk requests.
Considering that you feign client is already implemented or looks like this :
  @FeignClient(name = "external-api", url = "http://your-api-url.com")
public interface ExternalAPIFeignClient {
    @PostMapping("/endpoint")
    Mono<ResponseEntity<?>> sendRequest(@RequestBody MyRequest request);
}

Keys things to do ar the following.

Configure my Bulk request service.

Map all of my requests from the batch

Use Flux or MonoFlux reactive approach to send them in bulk.
 @Service
 public class RequestService {

     private final ExternalAPIFeignClient externalAPIFeignClient;

     @Autowired
     public RequestService(ExternalAPIFeignClient externalAPIFeignClient) {
         this.externalAPIFeignClient = externalAPIFeignClient;
     }

     public Flux<ResponseEntity<?>> sendRequestsInBatch(List<MyRequest> bulkRequests) {
         return Flux.fromIterable(bulkRequests)
                 .flatMapSequential(request -> externalAPIFeignClient.sendRequest(request));
     }
 }



fromIterable creates a reactive stream and flatMapSequential makes sure sequences executed one after the other.
Your controller should look like this :
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class RequestController {

    private final RequestService requestService;

    @Autowired
    public RequestController(RequestService requestService) {
        this.requestService = requestService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/bulk-requests")
    public Flux<ResponseEntity<?>> sendBulkRequests(@RequestBody List<MyRequest> bulkRequests) {
        return requestService.sendRequestsInBatch(bulkRequests);
    }
}

Please bear in mind that you might need also to deal with error handling and retry mechanism, by implementing error and retry events.

Many thanks for the solution.
